# Firemonkey iOS component repositioning & resizing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a **Delphi XE2 Firemonkey** application that I want to run on both **iPad** and **iPhone**.  The iPad and iPhone real estate is different of course and I have been experimenting repositioning and resizing (visual) components according to the platform they are running on - triggered by the forms `OnResize` event.  Started out changing the component `"Margins"` property with not much success (maybe that relates more to adjacent components...?) and then found the component `"Position"` property seems to do the job.

**Question:**  Is the `Position` property the way to go?  Or is there a more appropriate way using `"Margins"` (I seem to have read something about this somewhere, but can no longer find it).  Or is there some other method, maybe not based on the OnResize event?  (Yes, I am sure this is just 1 question.)

Brief details of the project - displays a costomer database record on the screen using around 30 components, mostly `TLabel` components, some buttons and search fields or 2 using `TEdit's`.

Thanks

Comment: Margins in FireMonkey is the opposite of margins in css. Try the padding property (=css margin style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really depends on how differently you want to use the extra real-estate.

Do you want to display additional information, or just stretch everything out to use the space?  If the latter, then you can use the **Scale** property.